# Exchange API incorrect Subject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exchangewebservices

When ever I create a meeting in Outlook, Subject field for an appointment is going through incorrectly. Instead of something like "Test" I get the name of the user who created an appointment.

[image]  -> bold = title, admin = creator name
[image] -> admin = creator name even though it suppose to be subject.

```
foreach (Appointment a in room.appointments)
m.Subject = a.Subject
```

Is this a known issue; Is there another field that is responsible for subject?

Comment: pjneary's solution fixed my issue. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not an "issue" but a "feature" of Exchange's workflow for meeting invites.  The default on a room resource is to replace the subject with the orgranizer.  This can be changed for a room with a PowerShell command:

```
Set-Calendarprocessing -Identity:roommb -AddOrganizerToSubject:$false -DeleteSubject:$false
```

Of course you need proper permissions to do this, or else bribe your Exchange admin!

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. Is there a native way to get Subject of a meeting?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question.  EWS Managed API is a comprehensive way to get data out of Exchange.  Whatever the item is on the calendar, the Subject property is correct.  Now if you have a way of going back to the organizer's calendar (via the Organizer property) the item on that calendar will have the original subject.